# Transfer PixelBox data with boost

Tags: sockets, boost, buffer, boost-asio, ogre

I get an image from an Ogre rendertaget.

I get the pixelbox of the image :

```
Ogre::RenderTarget *rt = _window;
rt->update();

int width = rt->getWidth();
int height = rt->getHeight();

std::cout << "width=" << width << std::endl;
std::cout << "height=" << height << std::endl;

uchar *data = new uchar[width * height * 3];
PixelBox pb(width, height, 1, PF_BYTE_RGB, data);


rt->copyContentsToMemory(pb);
```

After doing that, i want to get the pb.data (that's Ogre::uchar), write it in a buffer, and send it via a socket using boost. And don't see how to.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [http sync client](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/sync_client.cpp) for an example. The code you want is going to look like:

```
boost::asio::streambuf request;
std::ostream request_stream(&request);
request_stream << pb;
boost::asio::write(socket, request);
```